# Android Picker with highlight in Android .NET MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

In Xamarin.Forms I used to be able to use the picker from Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android just by using a custom renderer, as described [here](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20201204-CustomPickerRendererOnAndroid.html). The site shows how to remove the border of the picker, but also shows two possible pickers.

This is how the picker from AppCompat looks like (I've extracted the images from that website). It is also the default in MAUI:

[image]

And this is the result I am trying to achieve:

[image]

However, in MAUI, using either the CompatibilityRenderer, or Handler, or even trying to change the styles.xml file I cannot seem to get the second picker to work. The PickerRenderer as a CompatibilityRenderer is only the AppCompat one, the handler as well.

Comment: Did you try the code in the author's repo? I tried it in the xamarin.form project and can't get the effect either.

Comment: Yes, I have that functional in Xamarin.Forms. To get the bottom picker, you only need to define a custom renderer that implements PickerRenderer from Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, and not Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat

Comment: I have checked the source code, this is because the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer used the Andorid.App.AlertDialog but the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer and maui handler used AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog to show the popup.

Comment: And I have tried to use the AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog in the handler. But [the method](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/4f32463d017e50718aaf811a6a88672d8b6d234a/src/Core/src/Handlers/Picker/PickerHandler.Android.cs#L140C17-L140C18) will throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem (answered to my question [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1503178/how-to-get-the-spinner-picker-view-in-maui), but I've modified it a bit to better work in my case). By using a custom handler, it is possible to create the old picker in MAUI like so:

---

First create a custom picker

```
public class CustomPicker : Picker
```

Then make a custom handler in Platforms/Android/Handlers:

```
public class CustomPickerHandler : ViewHandler<CustomPicker, EditText>
```

Then in the handler, create the picker like so:

```
protected override View CreatePlatformView()
{
    var edit = new EditText(MainActivity.Instance);

    // Set the placeholder
    edit.Hint = VirtualView.Title;

    // Disable selection, cursor, etc
    edit.SetCursorVisible(false);
    edit.Focusable = false;
    edit.FocusableInTouchMode = false;

    edit.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        var p = this.VirtualView as CustomPicker;
        var items = p.Items;

        var n = new NumberPicker(MainActivity.Instance);
        n.MinValue = 0;
        n.MaxValue = items.Count - 1;

        // Set this to true if looping is required
        n.WrapSelectorWheel = false;

        // If there is a value already selected, select it
        var lastSelectedIndex = p.SelectedIndex != -1 ? p.SelectedIndex : 0;
        n.Value = lastSelectedIndex;

        n.SetDisplayedValues(items.ToArray<string>());
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.Instance);
        var dlg = alertDialog
            .SetTitle(p.Title)
            .SetView(n)
            .SetPositiveButton("OK", (s, e) =>
            {
                p.SelectedIndex = n.value
                edit.Text = p.Items[n.Value].ToString(); // Assign the selected value to EditText
            })
            .Create();
        dlg.Show();
    };
    return edit;
}
```

Finally, register the picker handler in MauiProgram.cs:

```
#IF ANDROID
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(collection =>
{
    collection.AddHandler(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerHandler))
}
#ENDIF
```